# Regarding hashcode() and equals()

Tags: java, hashcode

I have a POJO that contains `hashcode()` and `equals()` method that I have overridden , but my query is that what about If i make `hashcode()` method  comment then in collection lets say in a hashmap when I am storing the user defined objects then what impact would it have...and another thing is that if I make equals method as a comment then what Impact would it have If I try to enter duplicate records will it store duplicate records twice!

```
public class Employee {

 String name,job;
 int salary;

 public Employee(String n , String j, int t )
 {
     this.name= n;
     this.job=j;
     this.salary= t;         
 }

/* @Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((job == null) ? 0 : job.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + salary;
    return result;
}*/

 /*@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Employee other = (Employee) obj;
    if (job == null) {
        if (other.job != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!job.equals(other.job))
        return false;
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
        return false;
    if (salary != other.salary)
        return false;
    return true;
}
 */

 @Override
 public int hashCode()
     {       
     return name.hashCode()+job.hashCode()+salary;       

 }

 @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {  
     if (this == obj)  
    {  
        return true;   
    }  
    // make sure o can be cast to this class  
    if (obj == null || obj.getClass() != getClass())  
    {  
        // cannot cast  
        return false;  
    }           

     Employee e = (Employee) obj;   
     return this.name.equals(e.name)&&this.job.equals(e.job)&&this.salary==e.salary;
 }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
        return name+"\t" +"\t"+  job +"\t"+ salary;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're talking about the **impact** when you comment `equals()` and `hasCode()` methods alternatively. Didn't you notice by yourself what happens when you comment them out alternatively (or possibly both together)?

Answer (score 0):

Once you comment something out, it isn't compiled and won't have any effect on the rest of your program.

Also, not overriding the `Object.equals()` method means that `equals()` will only return true when the two objects are the same instance.  For example:

```
int[] data = data; //data to create object
mObject o1 = new mObject(data); //new object from data
mObject o2 = new mObject(data); //another object from the same data
System.out.println(o1.equals(o2)); //prints false even though o1 and o2 contain the same information.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you leave out `equals`, it will use the `Object.equals` method, which is `true` only if both objects are the same instance.

Thus, duplicate *objects* won't be added, but duplicate *records* may be added, if you add the same data through different object instances.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what you do or don't comment out, the *same object* (address-wise) can't be added twice to a set. (For any sane definition of `equals()` and `hashCode()`).

When you have two objects `o1` and `o2` that "mean" the same thing (have the same data):

If you comment out `hashCode()`, you (almost always) will be able to add both to the same `HashSet`, even if `equals()` says that the two objects are the same (or as keys to the same `HashMap`). This is because all the hash-based data structures compare objects by hashcode first then by `equals()`.

If you comment out `equals()` without commenting `hashCode()`, all collections will behave as if the objects are not equal. This is because even the hash-based comparisons check `equals()` after checking `hashCode()`, since hash collisions can occur even in proper implementations of `hashCode()` and `equals()`.

Comment: First sentence is highly misleading.  "same object" with reference to collections is completely defined by `hashCode()` and `equals()`.  It would be possible, though foolhardy, to define these to return different values for the "same object".